# How to split JSON file into multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, json

Suppose now i have some table

```
studentId studentScore ScoreDetail     StudentName Phone  classId Subject     
1          50          (a json value)  Doe         911    01      math
```

the json file is like

```
{
  "DetailList": [
    {
      "source": "homework",
      "count": 30,
      "user_id": 1,
      "order_id": ": 0
    },
    {
      "source": "homework",
      "count": 20,
      "user_id": 1,
      "order_id": ": 0"
    }
  ],
  "TotalScoreCount": 50
}
```

How do i make it into this

```
studentId   Score  ScoreSource  StudentName Phone  classId Subject
    1         30     homework       Doe       911    01      math
    1         20     homework       Doe       911    01      math
...
```

Let's say i have 10 student

Comment: JSON functions are higly vendor-specific. Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 0):

use
**OPENJSON** to parse and transform

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @BQ Learning Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104722/how-to-parse-nested-json-array-using-sql-server . I trust it give you a solution.